# openlayers bindTo event does not work

Tags: openlayers

I have a problem, the toggle check box won't work and the the console appears as follows.
 code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title> Me OpenStreetMap </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/ol3/css/ol.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/ol3/css/samples.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="visible" checked />Toggle layer Visibility

<script src="../assets/ol3/js/ol.js"></script>
<script>
    var center = new ol.proj.transform([11.57,3.86], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
    var view = new ol.View({
     zoom: 6,
     center: center
    });
    var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [layer],
        view: view
    });

    // bind a checkbox with id 'visible' to a layer's visibility
    var visible = new ol.dom.Input(document.getElementById('visible'));  /* line 30 */
    visible.bindTo('checked', layer, 'visible');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The map appears, but check box does not respond, and the console log says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Input' of undefined
(anonymous function) @ events.html:30
```

I went through this but still I do not get it [OpenLayers - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'div' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698148/openlayers-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-div-of-undefined)

Comment: There is no `ol.dom`. Where do you have this from? Did you look at the examples: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/custom-controls.html ?

Comment: it does exist, checkout

Comment: it does exist, checkout http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/apidoc/ol.dom.Input.html

Comment: Are you sure your lib is v3.2.1? Because in 3.7.0 it does *not* exist: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/

Comment: `ol.dom.Input` has been removed in version 3.5.0: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.5.0

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use this function make sure that your library is in a version below 3.5.0, because `ol.dom.Input` has been removed in version 3.5.0: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.5.0

> The experimental ol.dom.Input component has been removed. If you need
>   to synchronize the state of a dom Input element with an ol.Object,
>   this can be accomplished using listeners for change events. For
>   example, you might bind the state of a checkbox type input with a
>   layer's visibility like this:
>
> ```
> var layer = new ol.layer.Tile();
> var checkbox = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
>
> checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
>   var checked = this.checked;
>   if (checked !== layer.getVisible()) {
>     layer.setVisible(checked);
>   }
> });
>
> layer.on('change:visible', function() {
>   var visible = this.getVisible();
>   if (visible !== checkbox.checked) {
>     checkbox.checked = visible;
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: so how can I get my targetKey? I am using 3.6

Comment: There is an example given, I have included it in my answer

Comment: Toggling layer's visibility via the checkbox can also work without the `layer.on('change:visible', function() {.....` last part. I guess that simulates a full `bindTo`functionality : if there is anything else affecting the layer's visibility, also update the checkbox

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it happens quite often that there other ways to change the visibility of the layers. Therefore I'd rather use this completely than just in one way. Otherwise you might end up with confused users.